# Can Sass or Less be configured to compile just certain classes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

Let's say I have a large Sass/Less project such as Bootstrap, and I want to use one single element of it, (say, a text box.) Is is possible to have Sass/Less compile just the classes needed for that, referencing whatever variables and mixins that are across multiple files, just to compile that 1 (or 2, or 5, or 10) class(es)?

Comment: You can use `reference` imports  for example. Though in general the whole approach is weird, to use a single class (which is usually just about 5-10 CSS properties), you'll reference and depend on a 10k lines of code project with all of its auxiliary crap? Hmm... So the question is why can't you just write that single class code yourself (usually it's times less efforts and times more easy to maintain)?

Comment: Really what I'm going for is to have automated software crawl my code to determine what classes I use (or use tests in simulated browsers to discover the class list,) and just compile the CSS for those classes, to shrink resource load times and make files smaller.

Comment: That way it's more up to another kind of tools (like a "CSS optimizer/shrinker") rather than a CSS-preprocessor (basically the very purpose of a CSS preprocessor language/tool is to transpile from one language to another and not to optimize/analyze/minify/process-in-whatever-way the resulting CSS).

Answer (score 2):

You could create mixins that aren't executed immediately by adding parenthesis. In  [my less library](https://github.com/JohnSpencerTerry/StandardDesigns/blob/master/loadLibrary.js), I use a node script to create an autoload.less file which I can reference.

From there, I create my final classes as:

```
@import "autoload.less";

.myClass {
    #myLessModule > .aMixin();
}
```

I don't think this is a perfect solution but it is working fairly well for me, and the resulting stylesheets do not contain excess stylings.

Answer (score 2):

There currently aren't any features in Less/Sass to accommodate this. What you are looking for is a post-build process to remove unused CSS classes. The most notable currently is [Uncss](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) which has plugins available for most build tools (Gulp, Grunt, etc)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13268043)

Comment: @EmreBolat the link is simply to a project repo for a recommended tool. Answer updated to add more clarity to answer.

Comment: This answer seems to be the closest to what I was looking for.